# This product could not be added to Xcode Cloud Missing Data: product

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

I'm trying to create my first Xcode Cloud Workflow. I've clicked `Product` -> `Xcode Cloud` -> `Create Workflow` -> `Next` (through an introduction page).
Xcode won't allow me to select a product, and when I double click it I get this error message:

> ```
> This product could not be added to Xcode Cloud  
> Missing Data: product
> ```

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1 on macOS 12.1.

This is the only similar report I could find but no solution: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694852

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this?

[image: Add Product Page]
[image: Error Message]

Edit (3 March '22):

Xcode 13.3 beta 3 now produces this error when I click create Workflow. It does not open the popup shown in the previous screenshots at all.

[image: error xcode 13.3]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you tried the latest Xcode-13.3-beta? Some issues were fixed.

Comment: Also you need to go through the steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud) for CocoaPods projects.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I tried it on Xcode 13.3 beta 3 and have updated the question to show the new error.

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen Still no solution sorry

Comment: Looks like a code signing issue. Have you set the signing to automatic?

Comment: @PranavKasetti Yes, I've tried signing in and out of my account in Xcode too.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right developer account? If you're part of a team, then you should use the team developer identity rather than your personal one. I experienced a similar issue that I resolved by selecting the right identity.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I'm signed into the admin account of my developer account. I transferred my account from one email to another during the time my Xcode Cloud Account was opened, so I'm wondering if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Have you checked your App ID hasn't been accidentally created for another account? Worth filing a feedback report to Apple imo

Comment: @PranavKasetti Filed a Feedback Report and they asked me to send them a sample project, which I couldn't do.

Comment: Is the bug reproducible on any new project you create? If so, that suggests an issue with your development environment.

Comment: Also maybe worth testing to see if the issue is because we support watchOS when we are using iOS cocoapods only.

Comment: @PranavKasetti It doesn't work on any project. CocoaPods or not. Blank project or not.

Comment: You can send an example project with an empty new project then in the feedback report

Comment: Are you able to archive the product via Product > Archive? If there's a problem building the product for release, that might cause the workflow to fail.

Comment: @Mel No problem archiving the product. Xcode cloud doesn’t work for any project for me so it’s not an isolated problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error as well. In my case I was able to resolve this by enabling Source Control in Xcode preferences.

Comment: This issue was fixed in the last Xcode Update after I contacted Apple on Feedback Assistant but thanks.

Comment: This is not helping. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Same problem in 14.2 (release)